# TypeError: response.getContentText is not a function app script

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

right now i am working on a community connector for Google Data studio, halfway on it, but 
when i move to get the data on my project i get a error:
TypeError: response.getContentText is not a function  app script

already tried to disable v8 runtime on app script, other "get" functions but the error is the same, it calls response."anything" a non function...

i am a little newbie at JS/AppScript... any clues or examples i can look? since now thanks.

```js
function fetchDataFromApi(request){
  var url = '***************'
  var options = {
    headers:{
      'Api-token' : '******************'
    }
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  return JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}

function formatData(response, requestedFields){
 var item = response.getContentText().shift();
  var row = requestedFields.asArray().map(function(field){
    switch (field.getId()){
      case 'analytics_campaign_name':
        return item.analytics_campaign_name;

      default:
        return '';
    }
  });
  return [{values: row}];
}
```

Both these functions are getting called inside `getData()`:

```js
function getData() {
  // Rest of code
  try { 
    console.log('Fetch Data Start'); 
    var apiResponse = fetchDataFromApi(request); 
    var data = formatData(apiResponse, requestedFields); 
  } catch(e){ 
    dataS.newUserError() 
      .setDebugText('Error Fetching data from API. err: ' + e) 
      .setText('Connector has ended whithout gettig the data.') 
      .throwException(); 
  }
  // Rest of code
}
```

i have change the function response in this way.

```
    function fetchDataFromApi(request){
      *******
      }
      var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText());
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    }
```

console.log(response); returns me data from api fine, but on my data studio its now only give me null fields...

inside formatData() the response parameter is still undefined when i log it...

```js
    function formatData(response, requestedFields){
      console.log('response: ', response);
      console.log('resquestedFields: ', requestedFields);
       var item = response;
       var row = requestedFields.asArray().map(function(field){
        switch (field.getId()){
          case 'analytics_campaign_name':
            return item.analytics_campaign_name;

          default:
            return '';
        }
      });
      return [{values: row}];
    }
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: inside the formatData function 
var item = response.getConectentText().shift();
when i console.log(response) inside the "fetchDataFromApi" i get a normal JSON, but inside formatData its say undefined...

Comment: Where is the function call for formatData()?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: https://github.com/geraldovilela/DataStudioConnector/tree/master 
here is the full code.
formatData call is inside the function getData() line39, on the try statement.

Comment: Where is your function call to formatData()?... [mcve]

Comment: only place i call formatData is inside this try catch, inside the getData()


`try{
  console.log('Fetch Data Start');
  var apiResponse = fetchDataFromApi(request);
  var data = formatData(apiResponse, requestedFields);
}
catch(e){
   dataS.newUserError()
  .setDebugText('Error Fetching data from API. err: ' + e)
  .setText('Connector has ended whithout gettig the data.')
  .throwException();
}
`

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue:

You are using `getContentText()` twice.

`getContentText()` is a method of [HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response), and you are trying to use it from the value returned by `fetchDataFromApi`:

- `JSON.parse(response.getContentText())`

Which is certainly not an `HTTPResponse`.

#### Solution:

I'm not sure what you want to do with the `HTTPResponse`, but I'd suggest you to return the response as it is in `fetchDataFromApi`:

```js
function fetchDataFromApi(request) {
  // Rest of code
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response)
- [getContentText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getcontenttext)

Comment: its work but my data studio field now shows null data... not the data i am expecting.

Comment: I don't know what `getContentText()` is supposed to be like, and don't know what you're supposed to do with it either. I'd suggest you to either edit your question with a sample of `getContentText()` or create a new question, considering that your original question (the error you were getting) is now solved.